# Cython not much faster than Python for Basic Sum Calculation

Tags: python, cython, python-2.x, anaconda

I'm trying to follow an example given on the [Continuum Analytics blog](http://continuum.io/blog/numba_performance) benchmarking Python, Cython, Numba for a sum calculated using a for loop. Unfortunately, I'm seeing that Cython is slower than Python!

Here's my Python function definition:

```
def python_sum(y):
    N = len(y)
    x = y[0]
    for i in xrange(1,N):
        x += y[i]
    return x
```

And now my Cython function:

```
def cython_sum(int[:] y):
    cdef int N = y.shape[0]
    cdef int x = y[0]
    cdef int i
    for i in xrange(1,N):
        x += y[i]
    return x
```

Now I've got a script that pulls the two functions and benchmarks:

```
import timeit
import numpy as np
import cython_sum
import python_sum

b = np.ones(10000)

timer = timeit.Timer(stmt='python_sum.python_sum(b)', setup='from __main__ import python_sum, b')
print "Python Sum    (ms): %g" % (timer.timeit(1)*1000)

timer = timeit.Timer(stmt='cython_sum.cython_sum(b)', setup='from __main__ import cython_sum, b')
print "Cython     (ms): %g" % (timer.timeit(1)*1000)
```

And now my output is:

```
Python Sum    (ms): 9.44624
Cython     (ms): 8.54868
```

Based on the graphs in the blog post linked above, I was expecting a 100x - 1000x increase in speed, and yet all I'm seeing is that Cython is marginally faster than vanilla Python.

Am I doing something wrong here? This seems like a pretty basic question with a simple function definition, and clearly lots of people use Cython with great success, so clearly the error must lie with me. Can anyone shed some light on this and tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: The benchmarking is sub-par. At least run it some double digit number of times.

Comment: it seems to be not a question and/or the title is not right regarding the content

Comment: This code can't even work. `np.ones` returns a float array and the Cython code will raise an exception for that.

Comment: In a real situation you wouldn't use a for-loop to calculate a sum. Just call the `sum()` method of the array. Timing the sum of 10000 ones gives an average time 21.9 µs on my machine.

Comment: @RolandSmith: Hah good point! I just tried it and `def roflsum(b): return b.sum()` is actually a tiny bit **slower** than `cython_fast_sum`, but faster than `cython_sum` and of course way faster than `python_sum`. but anyway i think it was more an educational exercise for the OP

Answer (score 14):

I am not sure why you get that result. As a commenter said, your code, as-is, shouldn't even work, since you'd be passing `float`s into a function expecting `int`s. Maybe you left a `cython_sum.py` file lying around in the same directory?

I did the following. I created a **python_sum.py** that contained your exact definition of `python_sum`. Then I slightly changed your Cython code:

**cython_sum.pyx**:

```
def cython_sum(long[:] y):    #changed `int` to `long`
    cdef int N = y.shape[0]
    cdef int x = y[0]
    cdef int i
    for i in xrange(1,N):
        x += y[i]
    return x
```

I made a setup file to be able to build the Cython module:

**setup.py**:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
  name = 'Cython sum test',
  ext_modules = cythonize("cython_sum.pyx"),
)
```

I built the module using `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`. Next, I ran your test code with some modifications:

**test.py**:

```
import timeit
import numpy as np
import cython_sum
import python_sum

# ** added dtype=np.int to create integers **
b = np.ones(10000, dtype=np.int)    

# ** changed .timeit(1) to .timeit(1000) for each one **
timer = timeit.Timer(stmt='python_sum.python_sum(b)', setup='from __main__ import python_sum, b')
print "Python Sum    (ms): %g" % (timer.timeit(1000)*1000)

timer = timeit.Timer(stmt='cython_sum.cython_sum(b)', setup='from __main__ import cython_sum, b')
print "Cython        (ms): %g" % (timer.timeit(1000)*1000)
```

And I got the following result:

```
$ python test.py
Python Sum    (ms): 4111.74
Cython        (ms): 7.06697
```

Now that is a nice speed-up!

---

Additionally, by following the guidelines outlined [here](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html), I was able to get an additional (small) speed-up:

**cython_fast_sum.pyx**:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

DTYPE = np.int
ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE_t

def cython_sum(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] y):
    cdef int N = y.shape[0]
    cdef int x = y[0]
    cdef int i
    for i in xrange(1,N):
        x += y[i]
    return x
```

**setup_fast.py**:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy as np

setup(
  name = 'Cython fast sum test',
  ext_modules = cythonize("cython_fast_sum.pyx"),
  include_dirs = [np.get_include()],
)
```

**test.py**:

```
import timeit
import numpy as np
import cython_sum
import cython_fast_sum

b = np.ones(10000, dtype=np.int)

# ** note 100000 runs, not 1000 **
timer = timeit.Timer(stmt='cython_sum.cython_sum(b)', setup='from __main__ import cython_sum, b')
print "Cython naive  (ms): %g" % (timer.timeit(100000)*1000)

timer = timeit.Timer(stmt='cython_fast_sum.cython_sum(b)', setup='from __main__ import cython_fast_sum, b')
print "Cython fast   (ms): %g" % (timer.timeit(100000)*1000)
```

Result:

```
$ python test.py
Cython naive  (ms): 676.437
Cython fast   (ms): 645.797
```

Comment: Thank you for going to such great lengths to help.

I made all the changes you made:
* change int to long in the *.pyx file
* change the setup file to use cythonize instead of extension
* add dtype=np.int to the script
* run the timers 1000 times

Unfortunately, my result now looks even worse for Cython:
Python Sum    (ms): 2043.02
Cython     (ms): 6394.68

Comment: @user3325401: Hmm this is strange. can you try literally starting in a new directory, creating all the files from scratch as-is, rebuilding from scratch, etc., and see if you get the same result?

Comment: Success! Can't thank you enough Claudiu. I guess my file references got all out of whack.

Python Sum    (ms): 2037.7
Cython     (ms): 12.1749

Comment: @user3325401: Nice! glad that's what it was. and this was fun, i hadn't used Cython since pyrex, was a nice refresher. makes me want to use it in my codes now..